# EntityFramework Link table with only 1 primary key

Tags: c#, entity-framework

So, I have a Garment:

```
public class Garment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Slug { get; set; }

    public Kit Kit { get; set; }
    public IList<Path> Paths { get; set; }
}
```

and a Font:

```
public class Font
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Slug { get; set; }

    public IList<Garment> Garments { get; set; }
}
```

a Garment **can have a Font** and a Font **will have 0 to many Garments**.
I tried to make this up in EF by doing this:

```
// Map the GarmentFonts table
modelBuilder.Entity<Font>()
    .HasMany(m => m.Garments)
    .WithMany()
    .Map(m =>
    {
        m.MapLeftKey("FontId");
        m.MapRightKey("GarmentId");
        m.ToTable("GarmentFonts");
    });
```

but it has made both **FontId** and **GarmentId** the primary key. Really I reckon it should only have **GarmentId** as the primary key to stop the system allowing more than one font for a garment.
Does anyone know how I can set up EF to fit my scenario?

Comment: Just as a general tip, what you're talking about is a "one to many" relationship. It expresses both sides of a relationship. "One" (because a Garment has **one** Font) and "many" (because a Font has **many** garments). The concept of "many" includes the possibility of having 0, 1 or more possible relations.

Comment: What you've set up here is a many-to-many relationship.

Comment: Yeah I know what I set up, I need to set up a 0 - many relationship. @Flater, You misunderstood me. A garment can have 0 to 1 font and the fonts can have 0 to many. That's what the issue is.

Comment: @r3plica: I only mentioned it, as you initially called it a "0 to many" relationship in the title. It could've lead to confusion on our part (I was, until I read the question fully), or on your part (any research you may have done on the subject beforehand if you googled on "0 to many"). I just felt it was better to mention why I edited your title, to prevent future confusion.

Comment: ah right I see. Ok I shall update the title

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need something like:

```
public class Garment {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Slug { get; set; }

    public Kit Kit { get; set; }
    public IList<Path> Paths { get; set; }

    public Font Font {get; set;}
}
```

with the configuration:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Font>()
    .HasMany(m => m.Garments)
    .WithOptional(y => y.Font);
```

no link table needed here. The FK is in the Garments table.

Comment: This was the way it was, having it this way throws an error when a font is not defined for a garment. I need it to allow garments to not have a font (because not all garments do!)

Comment: when does it throws ? in an optional relation you must check if `property != null` before accessing it. Otherwise you'l have an exception (null pointer or property not set ton an object)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with an unidirectional navigation property you could configure your relationship this way:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Font>()
    .HasMany(f => f.Garments)
    .WithOptional();
```

But I recommend you add a `Font` navigation property on `Garment` entity and the FK too:

```
public class Garment
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  //...
  public int? FontId { get; set; }
  public Font Font {get; set;}
}
```

And the configuration would be this way:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Font>()
            .HasMany(f => f.Garments)
            .WithOptional(g => g.Font)
            .HasForeignKey(g=>g.FontId);
```

Comment: Nullable foreign keys are bad are they not? I thought using a link table is the way to go.

Comment: You use a nullable FK property when the one end is 0-1 (optional to set) which I think it's your case. If `Font` is required, then use `WithRequired` method in the relationship's configuration and remove the `?` in the FK property

Answer (score 0):

@octavioccl has virtually answered it, but I didn't like the reference to the FontId in the POCO class, so I changed mine to this:

```
public class Garment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Slug { get; set; }

    public Kit Kit { get; set; }
    public Font Font { get; set; }
    public IList<Path> Paths { get; set; }
}
```

I kept the **Font** class exactly the same and in the **DbContext** class, I replaced this:

```
// Map the GarmentFonts table
modelBuilder.Entity<Font>()
    .HasMany(m => m.Garments)
    .WithMany()
    .Map(m =>
    {
        m.MapLeftKey("FontId");
        m.MapRightKey("GarmentId");
        m.ToTable("GarmentFonts");
    });
```

With this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Garment>().HasOptional(m => m.Font).WithMany(m => m.Garments).Map(m => { m.MapKey("FontId"); });
```

Like I said, this is the same as @actavioccl, but without having to specify the foreign key in the **Garment** class.